# Problems with running Xamarin for Visual Studio 2017

Tags: xamarin, java-8, visual-studio-2017, r.java-file, build-error

Okay, I've been searching and searching and it seems that people have somewhat similar scenarios concerning my problem, however, none of the solutions presented even offer a sound solution. I've recently installed Visual Studio 2017. I went on to test the Xamarin Android Emulator by creating an app (named "Try") with absolutely nothing on it. Mind you, this is a fresh install of Visual Studio 2017 with JDK 1.8.0_152 and Android 7.1.1 (25). Right off the bat, the build failed. I cleaned the solution and tried to build again. Fail.

I kept getting these errors:

```
    Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       error: <identifier> expected
package try.try;    Try C:\Users\User\source\repos\Try\Try\obj\Debug\android\src\try\try\R.java 8   
_______________________________________________________________________

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       error: class, interface, or enum expected
package try.try;    Try C:\Users\User\source\repos\Try\Try\obj\Debug\android\src\try\try\R.java 8   
_______________________________________________________________________

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       error: class, interface, or enum expected
package try.try;    Try C:\Users\User\source\repos\Try\Try\obj\Debug\android\src\try\try\R.java 8
```

Great, so this has to have something to do with R.java 8? I go to the source and get this:

```
  /* AUTO-GENERATED FILE.  DO NOT MODIFY.
 *
 * This class was automatically generated by the
 * aapt tool from the resource data it found.  It
 * should not be modified by hand.
 */

package try.try;

public final class R {
    public static final class attr {
    }
    public static final class id {
        public static final int textureView1=0x7f040000;
    }
    public static final class layout {
        public static final int main=0x7f020000;
    }
    public static final class string {
        public static final int app_name=0x7f030000;
    }
}
```

What is wrong here? I haven't even began to start coding or tinkering with Xamarin yet. Can someone please explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. I don't know why, but Visual Studio 2017 put those project files in a completely different location unlike previous versions. Usually, it would have been put here: Documents>Visual Studio 2017>Projects>[Project Name]. It seems that the place you put your project is conflicting with Xamarin somehow. My suggestion would be to change the project location to what I mentioned above and then build the solution again. If that doesn't work, make a new project with the specified location and test it out. I had a similar problem and that fixed it for me.